# ffmpeg increase volume for a section of song

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to increase the volume in a part of a song. For that, I'm dividing the file (I know that part works fine). and Then I want to increase the volume for one of the parts. That's where it does not work.

This is my code:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ogg -filter_complex "\
[0]atrim=duration=5[a];\
[0]atrim=start=5:end=10[b];\
[0]atrim=start=10[c];[b]volume=10dB;[a][b]\
[c]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1" output.ogg
```

This is the error I got:

> Stream specifier 'b' in filtergraph description [0]atrim=duration=5[a];[0]atrim=start=5:end=10[b];[0]atrim=start=10[c];[b]volume=10dB;[a][b][c]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1 matches no streams.

I need to increase the volume from second 5 to second 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modified `[b]` doesn't have an output label. The input label isn't automatically retained. So the minimal change for a working command is to add an output label of the same string.

```
[b]volume=10dB[b]
```

But, in any case, this can be done in a simpler way.

```
ffmpeg -i input.ogg -af volume=10dB:enable='between(t\,5\,10)' output.ogg
```